# Rundeck SSO with KeyCloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, rundeck

I am trying to figure out a way to integrate Rundeck with Keycloak for SSO. But I am not able to find any way of doing it.
Can anyone tell me that which protocol does Rundeck support for SSO and how it can be integrated with Keycloak ?

Answer (score 0):

The [SSO](https://rundeck.org/docs/administration/security/single-sign-on.html) feature is exclusive to Rundeck Pro. You can start a [Trial](https://www.rundeck.com/download-now) to test its features and you will be entitled to receive support from the Rundeck team, that could assist you. Furthermore you could be contacted by a sales representative in order to evaluate such integration.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This is helpful.